# Can you wildcard route paths to multiple backends in Google API Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm trying to use Google API Gateway as the entry point for multiple backend services. The services have common endpoints, like `/api/data` that conflict with one another. I would like to pre-pend an identifier at the API Gateway level to route requests to the appropriate backend. In addition, I want to wildcard all requests versus explicitly defining every endpoint per service.

Example:

```
paths:
  '/service_1/*':
    get:
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://service_1/
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
  '/service_2/*':
    get:
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://service_2/
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
```

In the above example, I want to EXCLUDE `/service_*/` from the path that is passed to the backend. Therefore a client request like `/service_1/api/data` would call the backend as `/api/data`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have your tried to use a [Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-load-balancing) for creating an entry point for a gateway routing to multiple backends. You can also check this documentation to [understand path templating](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/path-templating).

Comment: Yeah, based on the path templating options it's not possible. And I'd rather not create my own gateway through Load Balancing rules vs. using the API Gateway product. I was hoping features would be comparable to another gateway, such as Spring Cloud Gateway. For example, using SCG you can specify a rewrite like:

RewritePath=/service_1/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

Comment: I suggest to create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com) if you really want to use API for routing paths to multiple backends.